# Microsoft Cognitive Services - Bing News Search API V5. So many misunderstanding

Tags: bing, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I'm working on an app that use the Bing news API. We are currently using the V2 but we want to update it to V5.

We have a problem with the TotalEstimatedMatches attribute. This count is updated radomly when we try to iterate with the offset.
Sometimes the data are not relevant. or when we try to sort the results by date, the dates are not well sorted.

Is there someone who did it ? I really need help.

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

You should only integrate the very 1st TotalEstimatedMatches return value and use that as a constant maximum-bound while you use the 'count' & 'offset' params to iterate through pages of the same query. I use python primarily so I will here.

If:

```
TotalEstimatedMatches == 250,000
```

in the response returned from the first 50 results of your query. Then if you wanted to get a massive list of ALL 250,000 links you would do something like:

```
# Assuming count==50 & offset==0

max_bound = 250000
results = []
while offset <= max_bound-50: 
    results.append(your_search_function(your_query, count, offset, **stuff))
    offset += count
```

If you were to keep doing offset calculations using the new TotalEstimatedMatches attribute generated after each query, you'll start skipping pages.

As far as the date-ranges go, I'm less sure. I think I read they're adding better functionality there soon.